# Service account authentication for Google Fit API

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, service-accounts, fitness

I am quite a beginner and I am trying to write a standalone Node/JS application that will run on a raspberry pi, without any GUI.

I need to retrieve physical activity data from the Google Fitness REST API without using oauth2. I understand it can be done using a service account (?). So I activated the Fitness API, created oauth2 credentials and a service account. Created a key, that I am sending in my requests.

It works in the Google Docs API as in the example below, but when using the same apprach in the Google Fit API, I get the dreaded "error 403, insufficient credentials for this scope".

```
const auth = new docs.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFilename: 'MY_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE.json',
    // Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single, space-delimited string.
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']
});
```

Does the Fit API require oauth2 authentification, or can a service acount be used ?

Thanks for your help,

Lorenzo

Comment: Your example does not use the Google Fit API. Once you have written something and have a software development problem, post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On their webiste it says that you need to use OAuth 2.0

["Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you."](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/authorization?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you, all sorted now.

Comment: So, I cannot access user data using service account? for my requirement i need to Fetch user Fitness data periodically, what should I do?